# Javascript - Remove child object from parent object based on path to child object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a path of the child object in a parent object. This path is combination of arrays and objects
`const path = ['one', 'two', '0', 'three', '2'];`
and parent object will be

```
const root = {
    'one' : {
        'two': [
            {
                'three': [
                    {}, 
                    {}, 
                    {
                    'deleterObject': 'yes'
                    }
               ]
            },
          [], []
        ],
        c: [], 
        d: []
    }
}
```

after doing this execution, final output should look like,

```
const root = {
    'one' : {
        'two': [
            {
                'three': [
                    {}, 
                    {}
               ]
            },
          [], []
        ],
        c: [], 
        d: []
    }
}
```

function that I wrote is,

```
const deleteObject = (root, path) => {
    let concated = '';
    for(let child in pathArray) {
        if(child > 0) concated = concated.concat(`[${pathArray[child]}]`)
        else concated = `[${pathArray[child]}]`
    }
    delete concated;
    return root
}
```

But its returning an error, Please suggest some function to do this.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Its keep on going to the loop, getting stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the last property from your `path` array (ie: 2), and then use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to walk down each property of `path` in `root`. Eventually, you'll reach the object which you want to delete from. You can check if this is an array using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), and then [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the item. If it is not an array, you can use `delete` to delete the property from your object:

```js
const path = ['one', 'two', '0', 'three', '2'];
const root = { 'one': { 'two': [{ 'three': [{}, {}, { 'deleterObject': 'yes' } ] }, [], [] ], c: [], d: [] } }

const deleteObject = (root, [...path]) => {
  const propToDel = path.pop();
  const toDeleteFrom = path.reduce((obj, p) => obj[p], root);
  if(Array.isArray(toDeleteFrom))
    toDeleteFrom.splice(propToDel, 1);
  else
    delete toDeleteFrom[propToDel];
}

deleteObject(root, path);
console.log(root);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```